# $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative rv, and $X = \mathbb E(Y|\mathcal F)$. Is it possible to show that $\operatorname{Cov(X, \min(Y, c))} \ge 0$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Given that

- (1) $X$ is a non-negative random variable
- (2) The distribution of $Y | \mathcal F$ is determined by $X$. For example, $Y|\mathcal F = \text{Poisson}(X)$.
- (3) $\mathbb E(Y|\mathcal F) = X$, where $\mathcal F$ is a sigma field

For example, $\mathcal F = \sigma(X)$.

is it possible to show that $\operatorname{Cov(X, \min(Y, c))} \ge 0$, where $c$ is a known constant?

Denoting $\mu = \mathbb E X$, the covariance can be written as
$$
\mathbb  E \left\{(X - \mu) \mathbb E[(Y -\mu)1_{\{Y \le c\}} | \mathcal F] \right\}
+
(c -\mu)\mathbb  E \left\{(X - \mu) \mathbb E[1_{\{Y > c\}} | \mathcal F] \right\}
$$

Comment: $Y = \text{Poisson}(\mathbb E[Y|\mathcal F])$? Can you provide some illustration of how such a definition works?

Comment: sorry, I made some mistake, and the problem is clarified.

Comment: Not sure if that can be of help, but by Jensen inequality, we have $\min(X,c)\geq \mathbb E[\min(Y,c)|\mathcal F]$ since $x\to\min(x,c)$ is a concave function.